# Hide/unhide sections based on the Account type pick list

Tags: picklist, page-layout, account, pageblocksection

I am new to Salesforce and came up with a problem regarding the account page layout

On the account detail we have the account type based on : client, supplier and customer.

When it comes for the supplier we have a section called Supplier with custom fields enabled. The same goes for the rest of the types.
Our problem is that depending on the account type we would like these sections to hide/unhide.

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 3 record types: Client, Supplier, Customer. Based on the selection made, you can set the picklist value. Then, you can create 3 pagelayouts and assign them to respective record types. 
Cheers!

Comment: Hello Shailesh,

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This works perfect when creating new accounts. What about my existing ones? Is there any way to do it for them as well?

Comment: If you are using standard salesforce detail page(Not VF): You have to extract the existing account records in a CSV file. Based on the picklist value, you have to add the recordtypeID against the record. And then update the records with the recordtypeIDs. If you are using the VF page, you can make use of javascript.